# Data cannot be assigned to state in interval function in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im getting data from axios async function and trying to assign to state in same function. When I print the values on console, i see that temporary value is not null but state is always null. when i rerender the page, state is not being null.

```
    const [Pickup, setPickUp] = useState([]);


    async function GetOrders() {
      const result = await axios(
        `EXAMPLEURL`,
      );
      setOrders(result.data);

      var temp = [];
      result.data.allOrders.forEach(element => {
        if (element.order_type === 'PickupOrders') {
          temp.push(element);
        }
      });
      console.log(temp);

      if (Pickup !== temp) {
        setPickUp(temp);
      }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
      GetOrders();

      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        GetOrders();
        console.log(Pickup);
      }, 1000 * 5);

      return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, []);
```

On console:

[image: console.log]

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to make a get request. Your **axios** function need to be completed such as ;

```
await axios
    .get("YOUR URL", {
      headers: // if you need to add header,
    })
    .then((response) =>{
     setOrders(reponse.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      result = { errorMessage: error.message };
      console.error('There was an error!', error);
    });
  return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you're trying to achieve, but you can't compare Pickup !== temp this will be false all the time, you're comparing object references. Js will return all the time those values aren't equal.

This function GetOrders return a promise you don't need to use  interval, you can use GetOrders.then(lambdaFunctionHere -> ());